# Error in UseMethod in personal package for R version 4

Tags: r

`UseMethod` works perfectly when sourced or typed:

```
add1 <- function(...) UseMethod("add1")
add1.character <- function(x) paste(x,"1")
add1.numeric <- function(x) x+1
add1("abc")
# [1] "abc 1"
add1(12)
# [1] 13
```

It used to work as desired in a *package* as well in R version 3.6.0, but not any more in 4.0.3. For example, I have written a personal package called `eztools`, where `relocate` is a generic method and `relocate.character` is defined somehow:

```
> library(eztools)      # eztools is a personal package written by myself
> relocate
function (...) 
UseMethod("relocate")
<bytecode: 0x7fac35b06778>
<environment: namespace:eztools>

> relocate.character
function (x, what, before, after) 
{
    # very long - omitted
}
<bytecode: 0x7fac32fd8728>
<environment: namespace:eztools>
```

Please see the `<environment: namespace:eztools>` lines above.

Now, if I call `relocate.character` directly, it works:

```
> relocate.character(LETTERS[1:5], 'A', after="C")
# [1] "B" "C" "A" "D" "E"
```

However, `relocate` doesn't:

```
> relocate(LETTERS[1:5], 'A', after="C")
Error in UseMethod("relocate") : 
  no applicable method for 'relocate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I am frustrated as I have had no such problems with R version 3.6.0 so far. It seems `relocate` fails to search `relocate.character` in version 4.0. How could I solve this issue? Or should I go back to 3.6?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I don't remember exactly but it's not R 3.6.3 but 3.6.0 perhaps.

Comment: Does the duplicate answer your question? I’m a bit puzzled that this works for you in R 3.6.3, since [the rules for S3 lookup were already changed in R 3.6](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2019-October/078562.html). I may have missed more changes coming later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I was mistaken. It was perhaps 3.6.0 though I don't remember exactly. I edited the question.